# WPF C# BackgroundWorker use for a method

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, methods, backgroundworker

I have a class Population that contains A method Evolve wich iterate until int variable generationsNumber < population.Size. I want to avoid the main window to tell "NotResponding" and to update a progressbar. I want to use BackgroundWorker class. The problem is that I don't know how to notify the ProgressChanged that value of generationsNumber has changed.
Thank you!
Pracicaly:

```
/////////////
MainWindow.cs
/////////////

void m_oWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Population p=new Population()
    ...
    p.Evolve();
    //Where to call ReportProgress? I cannot acces local variable generationsNumber that is declared in Evolve method
}
```

Comment: [How to: Use a Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Call `ReportProgress()` on the `BackgroundWorker` instance.